# Bootstrap Fixed Navigation Bar

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm currently building a website with Bootstrap and I was wondering if something was possible with a fixed navigation bar.  I would like to have content above the navigation bar (either a picture or text), but then when you scroll down the page, the nav bar would stick to the top without the content above it.  Any ideas about how to do this?

Comment: This is what affix is for

Answer (score 1):

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation">
<div class="container">
    ...
 </div>
```

http://getbootstrap.com/components/#navbar

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with some simple jQuery.  Here is a working example http://jsfiddle.net/pqLen8p0/3/.

The key is using $(window).scroll() as a wrap around your jQuery.  Then use $(window).scrollTop() to find your window scroll position.

```
$(window).scroll(function(){
var nav = $('.nav');
var height = $(window).scrollTop();
if (height > 100) {
    if (!nav.hasClass('fixed')) {
        nav.addClass('fixed');
    }
} else {
    if (nav.hasClass('fixed')) {
        nav.removeClass('fixed');
    }
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use Affix components used in bootstrap. Here's the working jsfiddle. http://jsfiddle.net/xpzy2ko5/

JavaScript :

```
$('.navbar').affix({
  offset: {
    top: $('header').height()
  }});
```

CSS :

```
.navbar.affix {
    top : 0;
    width: 100%;
    z-index: 2; }
```

Comment: So it seems I'm getting warmer on the challenge I have too. To get the nav effect like on this website https://www.sothebysrealty.com/eng, would affix be the correct way to do it?